# How to make forcus highlight for 2 objects at the same time

Tags: python, treeview, odoo, pygtk

I want both view below are blue, how to set it? please help me! when i forcus to the second line i want it highlight both of object are blue, not one blue and one grey as below.
Code like this:

```
ui = twin_gtk_builder('twin.ui', ['dia_support', 'liststore7'])
win = ui.get_object('dia_support')
##### Begin function tree view
liststore = gtk.ListStore(int, int, int)
liststore.append([1,2,3])
liststore.append([2,2,2])
liststore.append([4,4,4])
win.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
win.sm = gtk.TreeModelSort(liststore)
##### Set sort column
n = 1
win.sm.set_sort_column_id(n, gtk.SORT_ASCENDING)
win.tv = gtk.TreeView(win.sm)
win.vbox.pack_start(win.sw)
win.sw.add(win.tv)
win.tv.column = [None] * 3
win.tv.column[0] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('0-1000')
win.tv.column[1] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('0-1000000')
win.tv.column[2] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('-10000-10000')
win.tv.cell = [None] * 3
for i in range(3):
    win.tv.cell[i] = gtk.CellRendererText()
    win.tv.append_column(win.tv.column[i])
    win.tv.column[i].set_sort_column_id(i)
    win.tv.column[i].pack_start(win.tv.cell[i], True)
    win.tv.column[i].set_attributes(win.tv.cell[i], text=i)   

##### End function tree view
win.show_all()
```

and how it work

### [image]

Tried one more time with @PM 2Ring help, Thanks so much for your help!

Somebody did it like this, but i can't find his contact...

[image]

Comment: Can you share what your code looks like? what have tried?

Comment: yes, code is added already, plz help me to check it

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a bit of work to get that code to run, Sunshine jp. In future, **please** try to post code that others can run & test, especially if it's GUI code. Otherwise it can be **very** hard to work out what the problem is and how to fix it.

I'm not familiar with `twin_gtk1_builder()`. Is it a GTK1 function?

Anyway, I've modified your code to run on GTK2+. I'm not quite sure what you want your code to do. So I've given row 2 a background color of cyan. Also, I've added the ability to make multiple selections, either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> on the keyboard when you select with the mouse; you can also do multiple selection with the keyboard with <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrows.

When the window loses focus the selected row(s) stays blue on my system. Maybe that's a feature of GTK2 that GTK1 doesn't have. (Or maybe it's due to my window manager - I'm using KDE 4.5.3 on Mepis Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
TreeView test

From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840091/how-to-make-forcus-highlight-for-2-objects-at-the-same-time
'''

import pygtk
#pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


def TreeViewTest():
    def delete_event(widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    win.set_title("TreeView Test")
    win.set_size_request(320, 160)
    win.connect("delete_event", delete_event)

    win.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    win.add(win.vbox)

    win.sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    win.vbox.pack_start(win.sw)

    ##### Begin function tree view
    
    #Set up liststore data. Column 3 controls whether
    # background color of the TreeView is default or special.
    liststore = gtk.ListStore(int, int, int, bool)
    liststore.append([1, 2, 3, False])
    #Tell row 2 to use the special color 
    liststore.append([2, 2, 2, True])
    liststore.append([4, 4, 4, False])

    win.sm = gtk.TreeModelSort(liststore)

    ##### Set initial sort column
    n = 1
    win.sm.set_sort_column_id(n, gtk.SORT_ASCENDING)
    win.tv = gtk.TreeView(win.sm)
    win.sw.add(win.tv)

    win.tv.column = [None] * 3
    win.tv.column[0] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('0-1000')
    win.tv.column[1] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('0-1000000')
    win.tv.column[2] = gtk.TreeViewColumn('-10000-10000')

    #Set up cell renderers
    win.tv.cell = [None] * 3
    for i in range(3):
        win.tv.cell[i] = gtk.CellRendererText()
        win.tv.cell[i].set_property('cell-background', 'cyan')
        win.tv.append_column(win.tv.column[i])
        win.tv.column[i].set_sort_column_id(i)
        win.tv.column[i].pack_start(win.tv.cell[i], True)
        #win.tv.column[i].set_attributes(win.tv.cell[i], text=i)
        win.tv.column[i].set_attributes(win.tv.cell[i], text=i, 
            cell_background_set=3)

    #Allow multiple selection
    treeselection = win.tv.get_selection()
    treeselection.set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)

    ##### End function tree view

    win.show_all()

def main():
    TreeViewTest()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that this is **NOT** a good way to make a GUI. You should be creating a proper class, not adding everything as an attribute to `win`. Please see the [PyGTK 2.0 Tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html) for plenty of code examples.

---

### Edit

Ok. Sorry about my earlier confusion over what your problem is. At least we've now got a nice simple example of a PyGTK program that creates a TreeView. :)

Anyway, it turns out that I was right when I guessed that the blue color of the selection turning to grey when the window loses focus on your computer is due to the behaviour of the window manager. I suppose there may be a way to block that in the application, by playing with Widget attributes, but I'm not sure how to do that. And besides, it's considered rude for programs to ignore the settings in the users' window theme.

So the most appropriate solution to your problem is to make the appropriate change in your window manager's appearance settings.

In KDE the relevant property is called "Inactive selection changes color", as described in [Color Scheme Options](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/colors/index.html#color-options):

> **Inactive selection changes color** — If checked, the current selection in elements which do not have input focus will be drawn using a different color. This can assist visual identification of the element with input focus in some applications, especially those which simultaneously display several lists.

To change this, open up system settings (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> → "systemsettings", or the [K] menu → system settings), then go to "Application appearance" and select "Colors". In the "Options" tab, uncheck the "Inactive selection changes color" setting, and click apply.

... ... ...

If you're not using KDE you'll have to figure out for yourself how to change it; hopefully, other window manager settings interfaces and documentation refer to this property with the same name or a similar name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sorry for take your times, but i don't know where is it wrong, it's not work over here, i'm using pygtk.require('2.0') too. >_<

Comment: That's ok. I'm not a GTK expert, but I played with it a fair bit 5 or 6 years ago. But a few weeks ago I decided to write a GTK program that needs a TreeView, so I've been playing with it to get familiar with the various features.

Comment: yes, perfect simple way to set it, but i want combine it in my application, so i don't have to set propertise everytime install my application. i saw somebody can do it, but i can't contact him...:(

Comment: As I said earlier, it's not a good idea for a program to override settings in the users' window theme. But I've searched on my computer and Google, trying to see if / how it could be done for this property, and I can't find any way apart from through system settings.

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question, `How to disable "Inactive selection changes color" in pygtk`, and put a link in that question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840091/how-to-make-forcus-highlight-for-2-objects-at-the-same-time), so people will know exactly what you mean.